# What component will be started when receiving a notification without clicking through

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

If there is an application receives a notification while it is not running in background/foreground. Will just receiving a notification trigger MyApplication.onCreate()? What other component will the android framework start by just receiving a notification? Thanks.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by 'notification'? Are your referring to Android Intents and if so who do you think is sending them.

Comment: @MorrisonChang I meant Google GCM push notifications

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about push notifications (which are supplied by GCM), Android will start your GCMIntentService, which you need for a working implementation (you can read more about it in the [GCM integration documentation](https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/client.html).
Before the GCMIntentService is called with the Intent, the Android OS receives a TCP packet from the Cloud Messaging servers, which contain all the data of the notification. Only 1 TCP connection is kept alive for all the notifications, to save power. Using the API keys, the OS will search for the application, which should receive the push. If it has been found, it will call the GCMIntentService of that application with the Intent containing the notification. From there on, it's up to the developer what he would like to do with that.

(To save even more power, the GCMIntentService is not running for all applications. Instead, a broadcast receiver has to be also defined, which wakes the service up when a notification arrives).

If you are talking about the Android notifications, which appear in the status bar, the application does not *receive* those. Those are posted via the [NotificationManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NotificationManager.html) system service by the apps themselves. The developers of the apps can create, update and cancel those notifications, based upon the app usage, and the events which happen.

When these notifications are created, you can add PendingIntents to them, which define the action which should happen when the user clicks on the notification. Mostly it is an intent to open a specific Activity of the application. When the specific Activity has been opened, it can check its getIntent(), which contains the intent of the notification, and any extra data which has been added to it. (Intents can contain extras, like Strings, Integers, Parcelables, etc.).

A common use case in Android apps is receiving a GCM message, and then posting a notification in the status bar. Like when you get an email in GMail. This way the user is not interrupted in his current work, but can still open the app if he wants to.